# Nearest Neighbor algorithm that is fast for non-matches

Tags: knn, membership, n-dimensional

I have a dataset with millions of points in 100-dimensional space. I need to quickly check whether a query point is **not** within a certain distance to any of the points in the set.

Are there fast algorithms for it?

The algorithm may have false positives (say the query is close to another point), but must not have false negatives (say the query is far from every point when it isn't).

The difficulty here is:

- The number of dimensions is [cursed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). It's a vast space, but everything is relatively close together.
- Most KNN algorithms focus on finding the best candidate, and rejecting all points farther than the best candidate. In my case almost every query is a "miss" so the best candidate is consistently too far to reject even than half of the points.

Comment: for the kNN algorithm, the general approach is to calculate the distance for all training dataset, and then select the closest ones (the neighbors). Intuitively, I can't see how you can know that the observations are not close if you don't actually calculate the distance, and compare with all the others.

Comment: @Xiaoshi you may be assuming it's for some kind of machine learning? In my case it's a blocklist, so by its very nature I know almost all queries will be far from every point in my blocklist.